# How to combine forms from two different solutions together C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to C# and wrote two different applications using Visual Studio 2015, each with a single Form. I didn't know how to have multiple forms together in one project (should've begun that way, to my everlasting regret), but now I need that to happen. I already found instructions on how to switch between forms in a project, so could someone please help me putting them together first in one application?

Comment: pls see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to 'Add existing item' to one of the projects? Add the form to project and then call it from the other form.

Comment: I actually just tried that and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is very unclear about what your asking,

You can have any number of forms in a project by creating them in the solution (using the Add new or existing item options)

Every runnable solution has a entry point this is either a public static main or a startup object ie a form, page, window. from inside these you can instantiate you forms and then call their Show or ShowDialog function which will launch the form.

If you want to create a control library then you set the project type to library and add it to your consuming project as a reference then you can reference them as you would any form in your project directly

I would suggest looking up some tutorials online as this is very fundamental to using any OO language or IDE